# Using RegQueryValueEx and HKEY_PERFORMANCE_COUNTER to Get "Disk Bytes/sec%

Tags: c++, winapi, performancecounter

I've looked for examples and documentation, but I still can't figure this out...

How do you use `RegQueryValueEx` (*not* the PdhXxx functions) to query for something like `Disk Bytes/sec`?

I've tried the following:

```
DWORD type;
static union { TCHAR Data[32 * 1024]; PERF_DATA_BLOCK Perf; } perf;//Stack buffer
DWORD cbData = sizeof(perf);
LSTATUS s = RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA,
    _T("PhysicalDisk"), NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&perf, &cbData);
PPERF_OBJECT_TYPE pObjType =
    (PPERF_OBJECT_TYPE)((BYTE*)&perf + perf.Perf.HeaderLength);
```

but it just returns a header with no data. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't query for the data by name like that. Instead, you need to query by index. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can help you with some code to find out the appropriate index to query. Unfortunately, you need to make the determination of which index at run-time.

For example, the following SHOULD retrieve the performance data for the processor.

```
LSTATUS s = RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA, _T("238"), NULL,
    &type, (LPBYTE)&perf, &cbData);
```